# 'Script control 'x' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl()

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am creating an application that makes an ASP.NET page to pdf to print it. I am using iTextSharp. It showed an error in hTextWriter before, but i added EnableEventValidation="false", it surpassed that error and it showed the following one.
It works in single gridview, but not in multiview: main view.
Edit: i think the "login" script with "iduser" interrupts this script, because it shows that they contradict each other in debugging.

The error it shows after exporting to pdf:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Script control is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors(). Parameter name: scriptControl'
```

My code:

1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="1.aspx.cs" Inherits="abc"
    EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>


 <input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="Print" /><asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" 
             OnClick="btnExport_Click" 
             Text="Export to PDF" />

 <td>
                    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
                    <asp:MultiView ID="MainView" runat="server">
                        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
```

etc

1.Cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;

 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        form.Controls.Add(MainView);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        form.Controls[0].RenderControl(hTextWriter);
        string html = sw.ToString();
        Document Doc = new Document();

        //PdfWriter.GetInstance
        //(Doc, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath 
        //+ "\\AmitJain.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath
        (Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\exportedfile.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        Doc.Open();

        Chunk c = new Chunk("Export GridView to PDF Using iTextSharp \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 15));
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        p.Add(c);
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("exported file \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8));
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        p1.Add(chunk1);

        Doc.Add(p);
        Doc.Add(p1);

        System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader =
        new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(html));
        HtmlParser.Parse(Doc, xmlReader);

        Doc.Close();
        string Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\exportedfile.pdf";



        ShowPdf(Path);


    }

    private void ShowPdf(string strS)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strS);
        Response.TransmitFile(strS);
        Response.End();
        //Response.WriteFile(strS);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();

    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need hTextWriter?

Comment: For the    form.Controls.Add(MainView);
If i remove it, although the code will continue, the pdf will be blank.